# Safely modifying variable between two threads in windows

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, thread-safety, race-condition

In `unix` I can safely modify a variable within a thread using a `mutex lock` like-so:

```
int x = 0; // Global Variable we want to modify between threads.

void a_thread() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    pthread_cond_wait(&consum,lock);
 
    //critical area
    x += 30;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

}
```

What is the windows equivalent of this code?

Comment: If you search for *windows mutex* I'm sure yo'll find many hits guiding you in the right direction. Or you could use *atomic* variables.

Comment: And if your compiler is "new" enough to implement the C11 standard, there may be [standard C thread and mutex functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread) you can use, as well as [atomic functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic).

Comment: Could you provide an example?